# sharing whatsapp on webview

Tags: android, webview

I have android webview app and in the web source have sharing news content to whatsapp. It's works perfect from mobile browser but its doesn't work from web view.

its show text whatsapp://send?text=Hello world

this is my code

```
package com.web.viewers;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap; 
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import com.daimajia.numberprogressbar.NumberProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webView;
private String url = "http://www.myurl.com";
private NumberProgressBar progressBar;
private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initializeWebView();


}

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
private void initializeWebView() {
    if (getIntent().getStringExtra("url") != null){
        url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "initializeWebView: " + url);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    progressBar = (NumberProgressBar)  
 findViewById(R.id.number_progress_bar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }

public class WebChromeClient extends android.webkit.WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
        progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
    }
}

public class WebViewClient extends android.webkit.WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,  
  WebResourceRequest request) {


      return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);



    }


    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)  {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()){
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        showAlertDialog();
    }
}

private void showAlertDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage("Tutup Aplikasi ini ?")
            .setNegativeButton("Tidak", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Ya", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    finish();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

Add this below code in your `WebViewClient()` method and it will be working perfectly

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url != null && url.startsWith("whatsapp://")) {
                    view.getContext().startActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: this works but when i press the share button it launches whatsapp and after sending the message when i return to my webview it shows the whatsapp web screen and not my webview where share button was present

Answer (score 5):

It looks like if you are clicking a link with a custom scheme from a WebView on Android, that you now need to implement a handler in the WebViewClient.

To get this working, you need to update your implementation of `WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading` to something like the following:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,
                                        WebResourceRequest request) {
    Uri uri = request.getUrl();
    if (Objects.equals(uri.getScheme(), "whatsapp")) {
        try {
            Intent intent = Intent.parseUri(request.getUrl().toString(), Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
            if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
                startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        } catch (URISyntaxException use) {
            Log.e(TAG, use.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
}
```

Comment: this works but when i press the share button it launches whatsapp and after sending the message when i return to my webview it shows the whatsapp web screen and not my webview where share button was present.

Answer (score 4):

In the html code, replace:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello">
```

with:

```
<a href="intent://send?text=Hello#Intent;scheme=whatsapp;package=com.whatsapp;end">
```

See Chrome's docs about this here:
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents#example

Answer (score 2):

don't forget to remove `+` from url

```
this.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean  shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url != null && url.startsWith("https://wa.me")) {
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url.replace("+",""))));

                return true;

            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```